# Taxonomy vocabulary templates

Tags: 7, views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have three taxonomy vocabularies in my site and one of them using custom template files.. Parent and child term pages and that's ok.. But I don't want to use these template files for two other vocabularies.

I was trying to use [TVI](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module and I get nice views for these vocabulary terms, but I have one huge problem. It messed up my third category page.. It's override template files.

3 vocabularies: Articles, Blogs and Notes..

Articles uses parent-term.tpl files and it's ok, but blogs and notes uses views with TVI module. When I enable TVI module my article category pages messed up..

So what I can do? I love this module, but I don't want automatic override article term pages or nothing.. Only use this module for blog and notes category pages.

Answer (score 1):

To use TVI with individual vocabularies instead of all vocabularies, first make sure it is not globally overriding your vocabulary term pages. Go to Admin > Configuration > User Interface > TVI Settings (admin/config/user-interface/tvi) and uncheck the **Use view override** checkbox.

[image: TVI global view override settings]

Then edit each vocabulary to apply the TVI view override individually. Admin > Structure > Taxonomy > edit vocabulary. In your case, you would edit your Article vocabulary and make sure the **Use view override** checkbox is unchecked.

[image: Articles view override unchecked]

Then edit the two vocabularies you do wish to override with the appropriate view. The fields for selecting the view appear once you check the **Use view override** box:

[image: TVI enabled for an individual vocab, settings fields]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have uncheck overrides, but still my article term pages changes. Even I uncheck "Use view override." 

Is there any alternative for that module or is there some bug?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? When I tested it, I got the expected results, but there could be other factors at play with your set up. You could also try disabling the default Taxonomy term view if it's enabled and you aren't using it (though that didn't make a difference in my testing), or uninstalling and reinstalling the module. I'm not sure about alternatives or bugs, you could check out the issue queue for the project.

Comment: I just disabled all views, but it's broken my custom parent and sub term pages for articles.

Don't know why it won't work with my custom taxonomy module. Is there anything where I can trying to find solution?

Comment: Hey, I just checked this line of tvi.module file

// Taxonomy is last resort - used if no standard views are found.

I think I just need to replace module_load_include for my own taxonomy module, but I can't get it working so I'm going to ask:

How I can load custom module from folder "test/site/modules/custom/site_taxonomy" ?

Comment: I think that might be a question on its own! If you post it, it would be good to include your custom module code so others can troubleshoot. Also the TVI project's issue queue would be a good place to start with questions about why you're not getting expected results.